# Updating BigCommerce Pricing in Bulk with API

Tags: rest, bigcommerce, price, bulkupdate

I am trying to figure out the best way to update our prices via the API

Normal SKUs are fine, but the price of items with options seems a little less straightforward.

Using the GET v2/products?sku=XXXX there is only the base price of the item, not the price of the item with the option(s) selected

We also need the SKU of the item when the option(s) is(are) selected as my updated price list has SKU and Price

What is the best method of gathering this information, and then updating the prices?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The V3 API provides a much better interface for this.

If all of your product's options are related to SKUs, you can GET all of the details of the product with its variants via

/v3/catalog/products?include=variants

This will show you option information along with all pricing - the `calculated_price` property will give you an idea of what the real price will be when you click on the option values for that SKU on the storefront - so it will take into account (for example) Product Rules and other things that *might* be going on in the background.

Editing SKUs (such as their price) can also be done via the endpoint.

Example:

**PUT /v3/catalog/products/6606?include=variants** (where 6606 is the Product ID)

```
{
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": 25858,
            "product_id": 6606,
            "price": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 25859,
            "product_id": 6606,
            "price": 11
        },
        {
            "id": 25860,
            "product_id": 6606,
            "price": 13
        }
    ]
}
```

This would update the prices of these 3 variants on the product (you'd get their IDs from the GET response).

If the product is "simple", meaning it has no child SKUs, you'll also see the product represented as a variant with sku_id=null. So you can actually use this endpoint to update the prices of simple products as well.

Comment: Thanks for that @Nathan Booker

What endpoint do we use to update via each SKU? And how does that need to change if the SKU is a variant SKU, not the actual SKU?

Thanks

Comment: Another issue my developer has brought up, whilst the Calculated price is what the customer is charged, the price may be made up by various options with price rules. How would you recommend we handle that?
Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to include how you would update prices of SKUs with PUT. I didn't fully understand your second question about rules - can all of your products be represented by variants or do you need rules also?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Booker
Take this product as an example
https://www.darksidedevelopments.co.uk/products/vibra-technics-engine-and-gearbox-mounts-for-golf-mk4-bora-a3-leon-octavia.html
Each option adds or removes something from the price, so how do we control the prices in this instance? Since they are calculated by the price increasing with each option being selected.
The prices are currently set in the 'Rules' section on BigCommerce

Comment: I did a test using a copy of the above product (SKU is CopyDSD1275) with all the same options. 
I try a PUT to v3/catalog/products/1246?include=variants in the format you gave above, and I get a 403 Forbidden Error

Comment: If you are trying to control rules instead of using SKU prices (you should seriously consider just using prices on SKUs if possible), you can see these rules at the /modifiers or /complex-rules endpoints on the product. With these rules there's nothing built in to show you the calculated price, since there's a lot of information needed to fully calculate that price and it is not easily represented as "flat" data. This is why SKUs are better if it makes sense for you to use them. Regardless, these endpoints will give you the data you need to calculate yourself, and to modify the rules.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Booker